# How to find only Japanese language name and English name data in a table of sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a Sql Server table loaded with data from 2 language names. Say Japanese, English.

How to identify the language and its relevant data from that table ?
How to pull only Japanese data ?   i tried with this command didn't work 
How to pull only English data ?    i tried with firstname  like '%[^!-~ ]%'
after population I need to separate Japanese and  English names in 2 diff column  ?

sample:

For English i tried -firstname  like '%[^!-~ ]%'
For Japanese i tried -firstname like '[^A-Z]%'

select
case when firstname  like '[^A-Z]%' then  firstname

end as Japanese_firstname 
from  All_Users

Sample table

```
id | firstname 
1  |  steven 
2  |  佳恵
3  |  Yoshie 
4  | Fruit south  
5  |  果南
```

I need a query to produce :
is this possible to get ?

```
id     |  firstname_english |  firstname_Japanese 
1      |  steven            |   null
2      |   null             |  佳恵
3      |  Yoshie            |  null
4      | Fruit south        | null
5      |    null            |  果南
```

Answer (score 3):

One idea would be to `CONVERT` the values to a `varchar` (assuming that you aren't using a Japanese collation). If, afterwards, they contain `'?'`, then you know that the value contains a unicode character outside of the collation and therefore can *assume* it has Kanji Characters in it:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(100),REPLACE(YT.FirstName,'?','')) NOT LIKE '%?%' THEN YT.FirstName END AS RomanjiName,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(100),REPLACE(YT.FirstName,'?','')) LIKE '%?%' THEN YT.FirstName END AS KanjiName
FROM (VALUES(1,N'steven'),
            (2,N'佳恵'),
            (3,N'Yoshie'),
            (4,N'Fruit south'),
            (5,N'果南'))YT(ID,FirstName);
```